# For loop only takes last element in list?

Tags: salt-stack

Currently, I'm trying to disable and mask several network related system services using SaltStack under Ubuntu 20.04. Now, things got a bit confusing here. In the end, I need to disable several services, so I built a for loop accordingly, please see below:

###### init.sls:

```
stop_netplan_services:
  service.disabled:
    {% for services in [ 'systemd-resolved', 'systemd-networkd.socket', 'systemd-networkd', 'systemd-networkd-wait-online', 'networkd-dispatcher' ] %}
    - name: {{ services }}
    {% endfor %}
    - require:
      - dead_netplan_services
```

If I trigger my high state, only the last service in the list gets respected, talking about the networkd-dispatcher here. Everything else simply does not get applied. Why is 'systemd-resolved', 'systemd-networkd.socket' etc ... ignored in this for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated arguments in yaml states are ignored.

You need to generate separate states for each service. Also, the `service.dead` state has an `enable` argument, so you don't need `service.disabled`.

```yaml
{% for service in [ 'systemd-resolved', 'systemd-networkd.socket', 'systemd-networkd', 'systemd-networkd-wait-online', 'networkd-dispatcher' ] %}
stop and disable {{ service }}:
  service.dead:
    - name: {{ service }}
    - enabled: false
{% endfor %}
```

That is the general solution, though some states have an explicit `names` or `pkgs` or similar argument. You can pass a list to that instead of generating multiple states.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, [`names` should work for every state](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html#names-declaration):

```yaml
disable_netplan_services:
  service.dead:
    - names:
      - systemd-resolved
      - systemd-networkd.socket
      - systemd-networkd
      - systemd-networkd-wait-online
      - networkd-dispatcher
    - enabled: false
```

Comment: so, `- names` works with all states not just some states. it is written into the state system to generate a new state for each item in the list.

edit this can be reduced to not even needing jinja

`stop_netplan_services:
  service.dead:
    - names: [ 'systemd-resolved', 'systemd-networkd.socket', 'systemd-networkd', 'systemd-networkd-wait-online', 'networkd-dispatcher' ]
    - enabled: False
`

Comment: @whytewolf that should probably be documented better...

Comment: it should be. salt needs a lot of documentation fixes. the documentation for names is at https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/highstate.html#names-declaration what maks the documentation worse is the first example is a time when it should NEVER be used because it would cause slowdowns. in pkg.installed

Comment: @whytewolf -- This is interesting. Internally generating state declarations with `names` seems to be the same as defining them with a `for` loop. How does this make it more inefficient? Also, with `for` loop we can control the State ID and perhaps ensure they are unique?

Comment: @seshadri_c I'm not saying generally it causes slowdowns. the example is using it will pkg.installed. which has a pkgs function that works by gather all the packages into a single command to be installed. instead of running through a series of states each one having to run a separate install command, with all the overhead. which causes the slowdown mentioned.

Comment: @whytewolf - understood, your comment was specific to the example of `pkg.installed` where using `pkgs` parameter is more efficient than `names`.